# Changing path for destination of file after using put command in tftp

Tags: linux, command-line, path, tftp

I am using two linux machines to do tftp file transfer. The transfer is happening properly if server_args path is /var/lib/tftpboot(default path).
But when i change it to some other path for eg(/home/user/dir), the put command does not work. So for configuring a path for destination what is the way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will do with permissions on the directory and who can write to them. If you run `ls -al /var/lib | grep tftpboot`, take a look at the permissions (probably `drwxrwxrwx`) as well as the owner of the directory. Then, look at the `/home/user` permissions and you'll see that it will be set to `drwx------` which means that only the user who owns that directory can write to it - `tftpd` won't have permissions to write to that directory. If you're using Ubuntu, see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/TFTP) for how to properly configure the destination directory for `tftpd` especially the part about `chown`.

**Edit**: SELinux needed to be disabled (or configured) for `tftp` to write to the specified directory (`/home/tftpd` in this instance). Information on this can be found here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux-Disabling_SELinux.html

Comment: Thanks for early reply, but i had changed the permissions already and it did not helped. The permission for /home/user is also drwxrwxrwx. If i want to set  a destination path where should i set it in the same destination sytem or another one?

Comment: Setting `777` on your home directory is a large security risk. If you want to put them in a `$HOME` directory, can I suggest creating `/home/tftp` then `chown -R tftp /home/tftp` and then modify your `server_args` to point to `/home/tftp`.

Comment: i tried chown -R tftp /home/tftp and then modified server_args to point to /home/tftp but it is not working still. Put command does not work and gives timeout at end. :(

Comment: By the way i am working on redhat 6

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled? Of so, try disabling it to see if that helps. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Enabling_and_Disabling_SELinux-Disabling_SELinux.html

Comment: Fantastic. :) I'll update my answer to include SELinux. After that, would you mind upvoting the answer for me and then we can delete our comments?

Comment: Okay, sure i will do it